# Navigation Bar is transparent swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

When I updated to Xcode 11 all my NavigationBar have become transparent ([Transparent bar photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G73pt.png)). Why, I didn't change any code after the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new behavior of iOS 13 as it is mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/):

> In iOS 13 and later, a large title navigation bar doesn’t include a background material or shadow by default.

You can still override this behavior:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = .white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```